# Understanding posterior probability (Bayesian inference)

Tags: bayesian, inference

I'm reading this [online book](https://statswithr.github.io/book/the-basics-of-bayesian-statistics.html) and there is something unclear to me in [this table](https://statswithr.github.io/book/the-basics-of-bayesian-statistics.html#tab:RU-486prior) where the posterior probability of each model computed as:

$$\ P(model \ | \ data) = \frac{P(data \ | \ model) \times P(model)}{P(data) } $$

I understand $\ P(model) $ is a prior, and $\ P(data \ | model ) $ is just a binomial (probability of observing such data given the prior) distribution but what exactly is $\ P(data) $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a normalizing constant which makes the posterior a valid density.  In practice, we don't care so much about it.  It should be noted that

$$p(x) = \int p(x\vert \theta) p(\theta) \, d\theta$$

So it is as if you are averaging the likelihood over the prior.

Comment: Ok so is it as if I would say that $\ P(model | data) $ proportional to $\ P(data | model) \times P(model) $ ? If i understand correctly then I just take the $\ P(data \ | \ model) \times \  P(model) $ and divide it by the sum of all $\ P(data | model)P(model( $ to get the posterior probability of each?

Comment: That's right.  Often times, we just write bayes rule as a proportionality rather than an equality because the normalizing constant can be tricky to compute.

Comment: Thanks a lot Demetri!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Demetri.
Baysian inference is based on cause and effect relationship.
$P(effect|cause)$ is usually known.
Therefore we try to infer $P(cause|effect)$.

Remember effect is observable, hence we try to infer the cause given the effect.

$P(data)$ is just a normalizing factor which is total $P(cause)$.